# Making use of workers in Custom Sink

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a custom sink which will publish the final result from a pipeline to a repository.

I am getting the inputs for this pipeline from BigQuery and GCS.

The custom writer present in the sink is called for each in all workers. Custom Writer will just collect the objects to be psuhed and return it as part of WriteResult. And then finally I merge these records in the CustomWriteOperation.finalize() and push it into my repository.

This works fine for smaller files. But, my repository will not accept if the result is greater than 5 MB. Also it will not accept not more than 20 writes per hour.

If I push the result via worker, then the writes per day limit will be violated. If I write it in a CustomWriteOperation.finalize(), then it may violate size limt i.e. 5MB.

Current approach is to write in chunks in CustomWriteOperation.finalize(). As this is not executed in many workers it might cause delay in my job. How can I make use of workers in finalize() and how can I specify the number of workers to be used inside a pipeline for a specific job (i.e) write job?

Or is there any better approach?

Comment: What is the desired behavior of your pipeline if it produces more than 100MB of data per hour? Based on what you have described it would be impossible to write anything without violating one of the requirements.

Comment: Similarly, what should happen if some of the writes fail? The Sink will retry the write, but that may push past the quota.

Comment: I've just stated 5MB as example. Actually it is 10GB. I just put that into very sample way. Is there any way to configure the number of workers for sink job alone?

Comment: Are you able to understand my question? Please help us to get started using Google dataflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you have a repository that

- Accepts no more than X write operations per hour (I suppose if you try to do more, you get an error from the API you're writing to), and
- Each write operation can be no bigger than Y in size (with similar error reporting).

That means it is not possible to write more than X*Y data in 1 hour, so I suppose, if you want to write more than that, you would want your pipeline to wait longer than 1 hour.

Dataflow currently does not provide built-in support for enforcing either of these limits, however it seems like you should be able to simply do retries with randomized exponential back-off to get around the first limitation ([here's a good discussion](http://www.awsarchitectureblog.com/2015/03/backoff.html)), and it only remains to make sure individual writes are not too big.

Limiting individual writes can be done in your Writer class in the custom sink. You can maintain a buffer of records, and have write() add to the buffer and flush it by issuing the API call (with exponential back-off, as mentioned) if it becomes just below the allowed write size, and flush one more time in close().

This way you will write bundles that are as big as possible but not bigger, and if you add retry logic, throttling will also be respected.

Overall, this seems to fit well in the Sink API.

Answer (score 1):

The sink API doesn't explicitly allow tuning of bundle size.

One work around might be to use a ParDo to group records into bundles. For example, you can use a DoFn to randomly assign each record a key between 1,..., N. You could then use a GroupByKey to group the records into KV<Integer, Iterable<Records>>. This should produce N groups of roughly the same size.

As a result, an invocation of Sink.Writer.write could write all the records with the same key at once and since write is invoked in parallel the bundles would be written in parallel.

However, since a given KV pair could be processed multiple times or in multiple workers at the same time, you will need to implement some mechanism to create a lock so that you only try to write each group of records once.

You will also need to handle failures and retries.

Comment: This approach seems most promising, given the current API. Create a `DoFn<Record, KV<Integer, Record>` to randomly assign records a key 1..N. Afterward, use GroupByKey to group records into a `PCollection<Integer, Iterable<Record>>`.

Now, instead of implementing a `Writer<Record>`, you should implement a `Writer<KV<Integer, Iterable<T>>`. The `write` method of your Writer will write a group of records. However, as noted, you'll have to implement some mechanism to guarantee that each group is only successfully written once.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Sam on this and here are the actual limits imposed by our target system:  *100 GB per api call, and max of 25 api calls per day.*

Given these limits, the retry method with back-off logic may cause the upload to take many **days** to complete since we don't have control on the number of workers.

Another approach would be to leverage FileBasedSink to write many files in parallel.  Once all these files are written, finalize (or copyToOutputFiles) can combine files until total size reaches 100 GB and push to target system.  This way we leverage parallelization from writer threads, and honor the limit from target system.

Thoughts on this, or any other ideas?